# SQL Server 2008 BCP export throws: NativeError = 945, Database cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bcp, export-to-csv

I am trying to export to a CSV file using BCP like this:

```
 DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(1000)
 DECLARE @CMD AS VARCHAR(8000)

 SET @SQL='SELECT * from Pondor.dbo.tblLD'
 SET @CMD = 'bcp "' + @SQL + '" QUERYOUT "' + @FILE + '" -c -t "," -U"UserA" -P"Password" 

 exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

This does not work and throws the following error:

> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 945
>   Database 'Pondor' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.
>   See the SQL Server errorlog for details.

Doing a `SELECT * from Pondor.dbo.tblLD` works and returns rows. Any ideas on what is wrong with the BCP command?

Comment: When the user issuing the command is a member of the sysadmin group, xp_cmdshell is executed under the security context in which the SQL Server service is running. When the user is not a member of the sysadmin group, xp_cmdshell will impersonate the SQL Server Agent proxy account, which is specified using xp_sqlagent_proxy_account. 

Most probably your user hasn't access right to the directory where you want to bcp your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify a Server in your command. Add the `-S` option with the right value. If your server is the "Default" instance on your server you could put `-S.`

The steps to take to fix the database open error is explained by [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/02/sql-server-fix-error-945-database-cannot-be-opened-due-to-inaccessible-files-or-insufficient-memory-or-disk-space-see-the-sql-server-error-log-for-details/)

1. If possible add more hard drive space either by removing of unnecessary files from hard drive or add new hard drive with larger size.
2. Check if the database is set to Autogrow on.
3. Check if the account which is trying to access the database has enough permission to perform operation.
4. Make sure that .mdf and .ldf file are not marked as read only on operating system file system level.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it appears to be a database problem. I ran it on the test server where it is giving me the error, but when I changed to a different server it worked without any problem. Thanks for the advice and link which will be helpful in troubleshooting the test database.